# accessing my own tileserver implemented using MapServer via osmdroid

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid, mapserver, osgeo

I have a running Mapserver implemented in osgeo-6.05. I can access the map using a web browser.

Since I am trying to connect that map to my Android application I am using OSMdroid. I saw in Many forums that by using XYTilesource can connect a custom map server to Android application. Is it ok if I put my default URL

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/mwh/osm-demo/basemaps/osm-google.map&mode=browse&template=openlayers&layers=all
```

as the source to the XYTilesource .

Comment: Are you running your application on the emulator? If so you can access the host localhost using 10.0.2.2.  If you are using a device you need to bind to a routable address.

Comment: Yes, I can view my map using the device's web browser. Since I want to access it using a mapview, and not by browser window, I thought giving the URL as above is not a valid type of string to the XYTilesource constructor.